# using breadcrumb in Swing

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, breadcrumbs

I am working on a project where user faces 5 frames . Each frame contains the data to be filled . so when he completes the one frame and goes to next frame it has to confirm that the data is filled for that I want to use BreadCrumb(or progressbar).

so how to create a BreadCrumb(or progressbar) in java swings

I want to make similar to below  image in java swings

[image]

Comment: You don't get baked answers, you have to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you

- create 5 images to use as your breadcrumb images. Any basic image editing program can help you with this.
- Put the 5 images in ImageIcons, and put the ImageIcons in either an array or an `ArrayList<ImageIcon>`.
- Display the current Icon in a JLabel that is part of your GUI. You can easily set the JLabel's Icon via its `setIcon(Icon icon)` method.
- I would strongly urge you not to use "5 frames" since that is an irksome user experience and is not what the user experiences when using a professional application.
- Instead create 5 JPanels that handle each part of the process.
- Swap these JPanels in and out of your GUI via a CardLayout-using JPanel, one that I assume will sit on top of the JLabel that displays your breadcrumb ImageIcons.
- When you swap a JPanel view, you also swap an ImageIcon. This swapping will likely be done in the same method.
- Remember that it is Java "Swing", not "swings". Good luck.